# How do you show a window when clicking polygons in angular google maps?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

Whenever one of the regions on the map are clicked, it should open the window for that region, but it doesn't.

The expected results would be as follows:

[Here is how I want it to look.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xndAHm.png)

Here is my html:

```
<ui-gmap-polygon static="true" ng-repeat="p in regions track by p.id" path="p.path" visible="p.visible" stroke="p.stroke" fill="p.fill" events="events" clickable="true" >
</ui-gmap-polygon>
<ui-gmap-windows models="markers" show="show">
  <!-- Window Code -->
</ui-gmap-windows>
```

Here is the $scope.events.click function for the polygons:

```
for(var i = 0; i < $scope.markers.length; i++) {
  //console.log(model.path[0].id + " == " + $scope.markers[i].id);
  if(model.path[0].id == $scope.markers[i].id) {
    console.log("Showing window " + model.path[0].id);
    $scope.markers[i].show = true;
  }
  else
  { // hides other windows
    $scope.markers[i].show = false;
  }
}
```

Something to note. The log statement does show up, just not the window.
Here is a plunker: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mh1ZlL?p=preview)

Comment: Could you may some images so we can imagin your problem better?

Comment: I added the image link, but I can't display it in the post without more reputation. I'm pretty new to stack overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out an alternative solution to the problem. Instead of using a window for every marker, I used just one:

```
<ui-gmap-window coords="selected" show="windowShown" closeClick="closeClick()">
        <!-- Window Code -->
</ui-gmap-window>
```

Then in the controller we have a similar click function:

```
/*
  Events when clicking on a polygon.
*/
  $scope.events = {
    click: function(polygon, eventName, model) {
      // show the window
      for(var i = 0; i < $scope.markers.length; i++) {
        if(model.path[0].id == $scope.markers[i].id) {
          $scope.selected = $scope.markers[i];
          $scope.windowShow = true;
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

Lastly, we have a closeClick function to make sure $scope.windowShown is set to false after the window is closed. Otherwise, you cannot reopen the window on the same polygon after it has been closed.

```
$scope.closeClick = function() { $scope.windowShow = false; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to add multiple polygons so change your html to:

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" draggable="true" options="options" bounds="map.bounds">
    <ui-gmap-polygons static="true" models="regions" path="'path'" visible="true" stroke="'stroke'" fill="'fill'" events="events" clickable="true" >
    </ui-gmap-polygons>

    <ui-gmap-windows models="markers" show="'show'" coords="'coords'">
        <div ng-non-bindable>Test</div>
    </ui-gmap-windows>
</ui-gmap-google-map>
```

You need to define the property which will define the value as string e.g.:  `show="'show'"` `coords="'coords'"`

I added a second model just because i wanted to test it which multiple values. So my controller looks like this:

```
...
$scope.regions = [
    {
        id: 0,
        path: [
          {latitude: 39.13773735160255, longitude: -86.51972115039825, id: 0},
          {latitude: 39.137606286024926, longitude: -86.51961386203766},
          {latitude: 39.137664537422864, longitude: -86.51949316263199},
          {latitude: 39.13779768329436, longitude: -86.51960045099258}
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        path: [
          {latitude: 39.13673735160255, longitude: -86.51972115039825, id: 1},
          {latitude: 39.136606286024926, longitude: -86.51961386203766},
          {latitude: 39.136664537422864, longitude: -86.51949316263199},
          {latitude: 39.13679768329436, longitude: -86.51960045099258}
        ]
      }
    ]

    $scope.markers= [{
        id: 0,
        show: true,
        coords: { //you need an object containing latitude and longitude, so i wrapped these properties into coords
           latitude: 39.13773735160255,
           longitude: -86.51972115039825
        }
      },{
        id: 1,
        show: true,
        coords: {
           latitude: 39.13673735160255,
           longitude: -86.51972115039825
        }
      }
      ]

    $scope.events = {
      click: function(polygon, eventName, model) {
        // show the window
        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.markers.length; i++) {
          if(model.path[0] && model.path[0].id == $scope.markers[i].id) {
             $scope.markers[i].show = true;
            console.log("Window Displayed")
          } else {
            $scope.markers[i].show = false;
          }
        }
      }
   };
```

You should change your data models if you can e.g. regions where `id` is defined twice.